# VSTS Visual Studio Online Maven settings.xml

Tags: maven, build, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I've got a java maven application that i'm building.
This java app used a private repository.
I have the details (url/username/passwd) specified in my settings.xml file

Does anyone know how I can get VSTS build with maven to use a custom settings.xml?

Answer (score 1):

An alternative way would be [deploy your own build agent](https://msdn.microsoft.com/Library/vs/alm/Build/agents/windows) and configure the Maven environment and settings on the build agent. Then you don't need to specify the settings during the build process.

Answer (score 0):

ok i came up with an interim solution
i added my settings.xml to git and specify this with --settings ./maven/settings.xml

don't really want that info in source control so would love if someone has a better idea.